# How to programmatically get PlatformTransactionManager of a DAO?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, wicket, transactionmanager

I am developing a generic CRUD app with wicket , that can edit any Spring/JPA entities with a  AbstractDao pattern's implementation , such as UserDaoImpl , ForumDaoImpl ...etc

In my wicket page :
I have to use @SpringBean to identify which `PlatformTransactionManager` to use , such as :

```
@SpringBean(name="transactionManagerUser")
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerUser;
private TransactionTemplate txTemplate;

public CrudPage(final PageParameters pps , final AbstractDao<T> dao)
{
  super(pps);
  txTemplate= new TransactionTemplate(transactionManagerUser);
}
```

The problem is , these DAOs are using different transaction managers , such as `transactionManagerUser` , `transactionManagerForum` ...etc.

I cannot hard-code these txManager's name in my code.
I have to programmatically get the dao's txManager . How to achieve that ?

Thanks a lot !

------- updated -------

Well , I've solved this problem by passing `PlatformTransactionManager` to the CRUD page ( and use `transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager)` to generate a txTemplate ' , and it works well. Although not directly solve the problem , anyway , it works.

Comment: Why do you have a different TransactionManager for each dao?

Comment: Hello , not 'each' dao has different different txManager. Some use one txMgr , and some use another txMgr . Such as userDao , userLogDao ... use txMgrUser . And postDao , threadDao... which point to 'forum db' use txMgrForum.

Answer (score 3):

And why do you think you should be putting transaction logic in your code?  Spring uses aspects to manage transactions declaratively so you don't have to.  If you think you need to, you're doing it wrong.

Transactions should not be the province of the DAOs; services own and manage transactions, because there might be several DAOs participating in a single transaction.

I wonder why you need several transaction managers.  If you have several databases, you should be using XA drivers for each one and a single transaction manager to handle two-phase commit.

Comment: I need several txMgrs because the CRUD page is generic , not bound to any APP / DB . It should be able to process(CRUD) any class entities that with a DAO implementing my AbstractDao interface. Yes , there are UserServiceImpl and ForumServiceImpl with Spring's transactional annotations, but the CRUD app is unaware of them. That's why I need a programmatic way getting the txMgr of a DAO.

Comment: Page arrangement has absolutely nothing to do with units of work or transactions.  You're right - the page need not know any of those details, but that doesn't mean you need one transaction manager per DAO.  I don't believe your view of the problem is correct, but perhaps I don't have all the information.

Comment: Hello , I am not designing 'one txMgr per DAO' (see my comment below @bert) . The CRUD page may process many DB's entities. The UserDB may have userDaoImpl , userLogDaoImpl , userPrefDaoImpl , all managed by 'txManagerUser' and transactional userServiceImpl ; while ForumDB may have postDaoImpl , threadDaoImpl , voteDaoImpl ...etc , all managed by 'txManagerForum' and transactional forumServiceImpl.

Comment: @smallufo just don't do it. please listen to duffymo. It's awful practice